# Jqwidgets - jqxgrid not showing load icon

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqwidget

I am using the nested grid and each inner grid fetches data on expanding . I had put "**async: false**" for the row source  but after making asyn as false i am **not getting loading icon inside grid** .Earlier when i was not applying async as false the loading icon was coming perfectly .

Please provide some help or suggestion .

Answer (score 1):

If your Ajax call is with async set to false, the Loading icon will never be shown because when the Ajax call is completed, the Grid's initialization code will be called i.e you will not have Asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thanks for this nice info , is there any work around for this as i cant remove async as false . @scripto

Comment: As far as I know, the jqxDataAdapter plug-in used as a data source has a callback function - loadComplete which is called on success of the Ajax call. Inside the loadComplete, you can add your Initialization logic which creates a Grid or Nested Grid, loads Local Array, etc.